# SQL Server - Adding missing rows by group (expenses concepts)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by

Well I'm stuck with this:

```
Code_User    Code_Concept    Concept                 Quantity     Amount      Total_Amount
12           1               1/2 DIETA               2.000        24.000      24.000
12           10              APARCAMIENTO            2.000        0           0
12           8               COMUNICACIONES          2.000        0           0
12           3               DIETA COMPLETA          2.000        160.000     160.000
12           2               KILOMETRAJE             6.000        160         480
12           17              LOCOMOC. SEDE           2.000        0           0
12           9               MATERIAL DE OFICINA     2.000        0           0
12           7               PEAJES                  2.000        0           0
12           18              VARIOS SUPL. DIVERSOS   2.000        0           0
12           NULL            NULL                    22.000       184.160     184.480

1505         1               1/2 DIETA               10.000       120.000     120.000
1505         10              APARCAMIENTO            22.000       55.380      55.380
1505         2               KILOMETRAJE             12.478.000   3.360       998.240
1505         17              LOCOMOC. SEDE           0            10.000      0
1505         7               PEAJES                  26.000       242.300     242.300
1505         18              VARIOS SUPL. DIVERSOS   2.000        47.900      6.600
1505         NULL            NULL                    12.538.000   478.940     1.422.520

2816         10              APARCAMIENTO            1.000        1.000       1.000
2816         3               DIETA COMPLETA          2.000        160.000     160.000
2816         2               KILOMETRAJE             893.000      560         71.440
2816         17              LOCOMOC. SEDE           3.000        33.000      33.000
2816         18              VARIOS SUPL. DIVERSOS   3.000        4.680       4.680
2816         NULL            NULL                    902.000      199.240     270.120
```

I must show concepts: 3, 8 and 9 (missing concepts) for user 1505 with figures 0. User 2816 miss concepts 1,9,8.. 
How can i include all the missing concepts by Code_User?
I have got this result using this query:

```
SELECT --eh.Ex_Guid
eh.Code_User
,ISNULL(el.Code_Concept,'9999999999') AS Code_Concept
,CASE WHEN el.Code_Concept IS NULL THEN 'ZZZZZZZZZZ' ELSE MAX(ec.Description) END AS Concept
,SUM(el.Quantity) AS Quantity
,SUM(el.Amount) AS Amount
,SUM(el.Total_Amount) AS Total_Amount
FROM expenses_head AS eh
INNER JOIN expenses_lines AS el
ON eh.Ex_Guid = el.Ex_Guid
INNER JOIN 
(
    -- jerarquia de usuarios y tipo
    SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(VARCHAR,vhuos.Code_Seller) AS Code_User 
    ,pu.Code_Type
    FROM view_hier_user_organ_seller AS vhuos
    INNER JOIN prj_users AS pu
    ON pu.Code_User = CONVERT(VARCHAR,vhuos.Code_Seller)
    WHERE 1=1
    AND vhuos.Code_Sales_Org='1010' --FILTRO OBLIGATORIO
    AND vhuos.Code_User='10'--USUARIO EN SESION
    -- AND Code_User IN (...) -- usuarios multiselect
)AS u
ON eh.Code_User = u.Code_User
RIGHT JOIN 
(
    -- conceptos por tipo de usuario
    SELECT DISTINCT ec.Code_Concept,ec.Description,eo.Code_Type_User
    FROM expenses_concepts AS ec
    INNER JOIN expenses_organization AS eo
    ON ec.Code_Concept = eo.Code_Concept
--ORDER BY Code_Type_User,Description
)AS ec
ON el.Code_Concept = ec.Code_Concept
AND ec.Code_Type_User = u.Code_Type
WHERE 1=1
AND eh.Delete_Date IS NULL 
AND el.Delete_Date IS NULL
AND el.Date_Expenses>'20150215' --filtro fecha inicio
AND el.Date_Expenses<'20150510' --filtro fecha fin
GROUP BY eh.Code_User,ROLLUP(el.Code_Concept)
ORDER BY eh.Code_User,Concept,el.Code_Concept
```

Comment: Can't you join to a concepts reference table that has all values, and coalesce quantity & amount to return 0 where they're not in the transaction data?

Comment: Hello sasfrog.  Well im trying this on this sentence:    <pre>  -- conceptos por tipo de usuario
    SELECT DISTINCT ec.Code_Concept,ec.Description,eo.Code_Type_User
    FROM expenses_concepts AS ec
    INNER JOIN expenses_organization AS eo
    ON ec.Code_Concept = eo.Code_Concept

Comment: The problem lies in the fact that it adds missing concepts like this, it checks all the concepts in the whole result
and adds missing concepts not per user.

Comment: something like this: 12         2               KILOMETRAJE             12.478.000   3.360       998.240
12         17              LOCOMOC. SEDE           0            10.000      0
12         NULL            NULL                    12.538.000   478.940     1.422.520

13         7               PEAJES                  26.000       242.300     242.300
13         18              VARIOS SUPL. DIVERSOS   2.000        47.900      6.600
13         NULL            NULL                    12.538.000   478.940     1.422.520

NULL       3    DIETA COMPLETA   0   0   0
NULL       8    COMUNICACIONES

Answer (score 0):

let me know if the below query works:

```
select abc.code_user,
abc.code_concept,
sam.concept,
sam.Quantity,
sam.amount,
sam.total_amount
from 
(
select distinct code_user,t.code_concept
from sam as a
cross apply(select distinct code_concept from sam) as t(code_concept)
) as abc
left join sam 
on abc.code_user = sam.code_user and isnull(abc.code_concept,'') = isnull(sam.code_concept,'')
```

The above query will include all the missing code_concept.You can store this output in a temporary table. Truncate your table and insert the records from temporary table into your table  .

Comment: @Zohar : Please if those answers help you solve your problem, then accept and rate this answer. This will show your appreciation for the people who spent their own time to help you.

Comment: Im sorry. I have solved using php in a separted funciton. I had to solve this before i got your answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all thanx for your reply Sam. I finally solved this using mixing php and my first query.
Before this solution i have tried cross join but it didnt work cause of the amount of results.  With little records works fine.
Truncating is not an option. If multiple users want to work with the same report concurrency will preserve the results of the latest user.

Comment: this should be a comment not an answer